# DELETE in SQL Server 2014 while maintaining referential integrity

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

My instructor has asked us to DELETE a row from a referenced table.
The question is: 
Delete operator 4. Don't forget referential integrity, but do not delete any trips or vehicles.

I understand cascade delete and referential integrity but cannot wrap my mind around this. To clarify, I know that Cascade delete would allow for the removal of the operator but would also delete the trips. He does not want the trips or any other referencing table to change.

I though it might be a trick question and just make all the fields of Operator 4 Null but they require a value so that's a no go.

Operator 4 is referenced by a table named Runs.
The Runs table is referenced by a table named Schedule.
The Schedule table is referenced by a table named Trips.

How can I DELETE operator 4 while maintaining referential integrity or is there an angle I'm not looking at it from.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is the Introduction class for SQL so I assume it is not as complicated as I am making it.

Comment: You just gotta love a good oxymoron: `I understand cascade delete and referential integrity but cannot wrap my mind around this.` In the words of Hollywood's greatest spy: Which is it, baby, Spitz or Swallows?

Comment: You could delete the operator and assign a different operator to the referencing rows in the Runs table.

Comment: I'd like to see a database diagram to ensure what is said about ref. integrity

Answer (score 0):

If FK cols are nullable, you can set them to null and delete the former referenced records.